# I'd like to make a list of names in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

We have a Church death insurance and of course we list down the names. If a member signs up, there's an "add" in the name. If said member opts out, we add a row below, paste his name and replace "add" with "drop". So there's a duplicate but technically not since the one has an "add" and the other has a "drop". If said member dies, same thing: add a row, paste his name then we put [deceased].

The format of the information inside the cell is Last name, First name status name of church.

```
ABA, ADONIS  Add Upper Sumilop Church
ANG, NICK  Add Upper Sumilop Church
ANG, NICK  Drop Upper Sumilop Church
CAW, DERNA Add Vetarba/Talagutong Church
CAW, DERNA Deceased Vetarba/Talagutong Church
```

I'd like to make one list of both 'active' (didn't drop) and 'alive' (didn't die) members. Based on the example above, I'd like to make a list where I can show Aba, Adonis.

I was able to make a list where on one column, there's the dropped members, and on the other the members who have died. these columns are adjacent to each other but non-adjacent to the column of the original list.

I wasn't part of the program from the start up until they've already established the current system I'm working on now.

*they're enclosed in brackets instead of being in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

query it:

```
=QUERY({A:A}; "where not lower(Col1) contains 'deceased'"; )
```

[image]

```
=QUERY({A:A}; 
 "where not lower(Col1) contains 'deceased'
    and not lower(Col1) contains 'drop'"; )
```

or:

```
=QUERY({A:A}; "where lower(Col1) contains 'add'"; )
```